# Fried something when powering arduino with 9V in 5v pin and gnd in gnd pin?

Tags: arduino

As the title says, I put 9V from battery to 5V pin and ground to ground pin  and i wanted to upload something to arduino Uno and i got the error: 
**stk500_recv(); programmer is not responding
Problem uploading to board...**

SO, did I ruin my Arduino or is there some sort of fix for this error, because i have been googling for the last hour and every answer i have seen I tried and it still didn't work...

I have already tried reinstalling Arduino IDE and drivers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 5V is an output pin, no input! The supply have to be connected with the Vin/Vcc pin like this:
[image]

Comment: Yeah well i figured. Well I will have to buy a new arduino.... Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 1):

The 5v header on your board is intended for only 5 volt max (as long under 6 volts).
Anything above will fry, or at least damage your Arduino.
This because you are bypassing the protection from its board.

In your case, you should power it through the 9volt jack plug (in front next to USB input)